# Is it possible to view OSX .keychain files on Windows?

Tags: windows, macos, keychain

I was wondering if there is any way to (at least) view OSX .keychain files under Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I have not found any 3rd party software that allows the keychain file to be opened on Windows....

Now, you might be able to view them under Unix / Linux, since there are Mac OS X command line tools to access the key chain.